# WPF MVVM Ask for save before exit user control (Not before exit application)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I'm writing a C# WPF Application using MVVM.

In this application I have a user Control which displays items and user can modify, delete or add items. When the user save after any modification save() method is called to save the work.

Now I want to show message to ask for save before exit the current **user control**.
Althought I used the same approach described below with the **window** MainView.xaml and it work very well to ask for confirmation when I want to exit APPLICATION by clicking (X) button.

**MyView.xaml**:

```
     <UserControl
        ...
        xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
     ...>
            <dxmvvm:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" EventName="Loaded" />
                    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" EventName="Closing"  PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                </dxmvvm:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid>
     ...
    </Grid>

    </UserControl>
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
[Command]
        public void Exit(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_editable)
            {
                switch (MessageBoxService.Show("Messages.QuitRequest", "Messages.Quit", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question))
                {
                    case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                        WithSave();
                        break;

                    case MessageBoxResult.No:
                        WithoutSave();
                        break;

                    case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                        e.Cancel = true;
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
```

**MyView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class XsltEditorView : UserControl
    {
        public XsltEditorView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
```

Have any idea that allow me to know why exit command isn't fired as expected ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been using advanced WPF/MVVM for 6 years and never seen commands implemented like this. Where did you get that command attribute from? UserControl doesn't have a closing event?

Comment: @GlenThomas To be fair, an attribute on a method would be a much nicer way of declaring a command. I too would like to know where you're getting this from.

Comment: I'm new with WPF/MVVM. I believe it's better to focus on the solution and find answer to my question than to ask "where did I get that command". At least we agree that this implementation doesn't give us result. So have you a solution please !

Comment: The guidelines for SO questions suggest that your question should be self-contained and reproducible. At the moment it's neither of these things because it's incomplete and none of us know how to duplicate your circumstances. Your code might be completely error free at this point, but it's impossible to verify that or suggest fixes without knowing how it works. Are you using any third party libraries that allow you to declare Commands with an attribute, and if so which ones?

Comment: OK forget my Code. And let me pose my question differently. I'm new new with WPF MVVM and I want to know how to save modification that happen in my User when navigating between View without clicking in the save button ?